# What can be done about a HIGH Ping in Overwatch?

Tags: technical-issues, overwatch

Hello guys I have a question about Overwatch, in general my ping is about 30 ms,but sometimes it goes incredible high and I don't know why:

[image]

after a little bit of lagging (about 2 min) my game crashes:

[image]

So what can be done about it?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Seems like a problem with your internet connection.

Comment: call your ISP. threaten them to switch company if they don't do anything about it... Enjoy your sudden increase in stability.

Comment: @Karlyr That's great and all, and sometimes it works, but if that ISP is the OP's only choice, then threatening to leave will fall on deaf ears. Regardless, calling the ISP and getting them to help you figure it out will help; that's what you pay them for.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf That's what I meant... Just wanted to be sorta funny... This is still only a comment not an answer...

Comment: I have been noticing ping spikes (and occasional crashes) related to browser activity.  Like if you have a site open with aggressive ads, it will hurt your connection.  Usually I go through and close everything, or if I want to browse between games I disable javascript and that solves things.

Comment: You must hunt the mythical Bandwidth creature in the wilds of Internetland. Slay this beast and rub it's blood into the wires which connect you to the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

By my own research, if you are using WiFi, you could receive huge latency (lag) spikes. Try using an Ethernet cord, connected to a wall jack or your router, if you have one.

Comment: Well the op doesn't looks like an active user, so even if you asked clarification I bet he would not have answered...

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me occasionally for different reasons. Check the following:

1. WiFi strengh. If you're far from your router, you might experience higher lag.
2. Simultaneous WiFi use. If multiple people are using the WiFi, especially for other online games or streaming services (such as YouTube or Netflix), the lag will increase.
3. PC temperature. No joke, my computer gets higher lag when it's overheating. If your computer is overheating, try cooling it. I find that frozen water bottles works in my case, although they do produce water from condensation.
4. Server location. In the Overwatch launcher, make sure you select the region that is most appropriate for your location. If you live in the US, make sure you select "Americas" or you will experience higher lag.
5. Groupmates' locations. If you group with people that live far enough away from you, the Overwatch server used for the match might be further than normal for you, giving you higher lag.
6. Available RAM. If you're running other programs while playing Overwatch, they might compete for processing resources. In my case, Google Chrome hampers Overwatch everytime, so I have to close Chrome in order to play Overwatch. You can press CTRL+SHIFT+ESC to open Task Manager in Windows, and that should show you which other programs might be negatively effecting Overwatch's performance.

You might also want to try getting a wired connection, like cocohead781 said. I've tried it, but in my case it didn't make much of a difference. Still, it's an option.

I hope this helps! ^_^

Comment: Most of this is decent advice, though I have a few nitpicks: 1) If you insist on using frozen water bottles to cool your computer (oh god), please make sure to wrap the bottle in a towel or something. You know what's worse then high ping? A short-circuited motherboard. 2) I don't think RAM has anything to do with ping. If anything, it will decrease your FPS, which is a similar but unrelated problem.

Comment: Agreed on both accounts. 1) The water isn't an issue in my case, tho I understand for a lot people it will be. 2) Yeah it causes the game to slow down, which is a similar symptom to lag, so I included it anyways