# Overwatch keep losing connection to server

Tags: technical-issues, overwatch

As the title suggests, I keep on losing connection to the server mid game. 
I can reconnect by entering my credentials on the login screen, but the issue still exist after logging back in.

The issue still exists and I cannot play any match for more than a minute. None of the game modes work except for Training Range.

I have been digging around the Overwatch tech support forums and nothing seems to work for me. The issue happens earlier today after the first one and a half hour.

Any help will be appreciated as I'm desperate to jump back in to the game again.

Comment: Its only on overwatch and by game i meant match
Thanks for correcting me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can be done about a HIGH Ping in Overwatch?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292650/what-can-be-done-about-a-high-ping-in-overwatch)

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems and the problem is usually my router or internet speed.  As Overwatch requires a constant connection for your game to be in sync with the server, even dropping a few seconds of packets can make your client/the server believe you've lost connection and boot you out.

Check your internet speeds on [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) or by Googling "speed test."  If you get a poor result, consider upgrading your internet speeds.  If you get a significantly faster and more consistent connection when plugged in to your router via ethernet, then consider upgrading your router first.

Comment: For actual packet loss testing, you may actually want to also visit www.pingtest.net (also powered by Ookla).  Note that it does require Java for the packet loss portion of the test.  (Which, personally, I consider a pain to setup, since install doesn't always work)

Comment: While your answer is a good start to look for the problem, testing your internet _speed_ is not the same as testing the _consistency_ of the connection. If I stream video when far away from my router, I notice that the buffering happens in chunks (very inconsistent network), but each chunk still does a lot of buffering (high speed network). That being said, a _sufficiently_ inconsistent network connection will also show lowered network speeds.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you might be having an issue with your firewall. Go [here](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/300479) and follow the steps to open the ports for Overwatch.

TCP: 1119, 3724, 6113, 80

UDP: 6250, 5062, 5060, 12000-64000, 3478, 3479

Comment: If the problem is a firewall setting, the OP would experience a complete inability to connect. Not an intermittent disconnect at random intervals.